# Multiple copies of the same object in the browser with Ember and a remote data store

Tags: ember.js

I've got the following code:

```
App.ListsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // This get's all the lists from the server
    return App.List.findAll()
  }
});

App.ListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    // This gets a single list from the server
    // Now there are two copies of the same list!
    // (one from the line below, and on from App.List.findAll)
    return App.List.findById(params.list_id)
  },
});
```

Both the ListsController and ListController exist on the same page. When I navigate directly to a list `/lists/:list_id` and edit a list, then click on a `{{#linkTo list l}}` link, the original un-edited list shows up.

I think what I want is to have only one copy of each list in the browser at a time. Or maybe there is a better, more idiomatic solution?

I should mention, I am not using Ember Data. I'm using jQuery AJAX to get my data.

EDIT:

I think this is poorly worded. I'm trying to figure out how to have two controllers on the same page. One controller has a list of objects, the other controller has a detail view of one of those objects. What I've found is that the object in the detail view needs to be the same as the object in the list.

This seems to work find when starting with the list view and an "empty" index view. Clicking on an object using {{linkTo item}} works great. It's when I deep link to the object that I get duplicate copies of the same object (because I grab the list and the single item off the server).

These multiple objects then allow for data to seem "out of sync".

What's a good strategy for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conceptual solution to your issue is an Identity Map. Martin Fowler describes it here: ["Ensures that each object gets loaded only once by keeping every loaded object in a map. Looks up objects using the map when referring to them."](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html)

ember-data and ember-model include an identity map for the same reason that you have run into.

A simple implementation that you may be able to adapt to your app is here:
https://github.com/shinetech/backbone-identity-map/blob/master/backbone-identity-map.js

Comment: Thanks, @Luke Melina. This is great to know. Do you know how this would work with two controllers? One of the controllers loads a list of objects and the other loads a single object (the single object is included in the list of objects from the other controller). This seems like a common situation to have (in fact, the peepcode screencast builds an app very similar to this), so I'm feeling like there may be a simple solution or somewhere that I'm not doing it the idiomatic ember way.

Comment: For the simple use case of two controllers only, you could accomplish this by having the single object controller be looked up from the list controller's collection